# Why do I get an error when plotting with iloc, but not when using the column names?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib

I collected the data from excel using pandas and .iloc for x and y axis
and then plot with the code below. But it only shows an error message.
However if I use [columns] for plot then no problem working code also attached below

I don't know what's different between them.

Here is the code which produces the error:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.pyplot import cm
import numpy as np

df=pd.read_excel('F:\\test\\test.xlsm', sheet_name='sheet1')

x=df.iloc[0:,0:1]
y=df.iloc[0:,1:2]

plt.plot(x,y)
plt.show()
```

Here are the errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\jdf.jang.CORP\PycharmProjects\excel2\excel_graph.py", line 13, in <module>
    plt.plot(x,y)
  File "C:\Users\jdf.jang.CORP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py", line 2757, in plot
    return gca().plot(
  File "C:\Users\jdf.jang.CORP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_axes.py", line 1632, in plot
    lines = [*self._get_lines(*args, data=data, **kwargs)]
  File "C:\Users\jdf.jang.CORP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_base.py", line 312, in __call__
    yield from self._plot_args(this, kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\jdf.jang.CORP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_base.py", line 487, in _plot_args
    x = _check_1d(xy[0])
  File "C:\Users\jdf.jang.CORP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\cbook\__init__.py", line 1327, in _check_1d
    ndim = x[:, None].ndim
  File "C:\Users\jdf.jang.CORP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 3505, in __getitem__
    indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)
  File "C:\Users\jdf.jang.CORP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 3628, in get_loc
    self._check_indexing_error(key)
  File "C:\Users\jdf.jang.CORP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 5637, in _check_indexing_error
    raise InvalidIndexError(key)
pandas.errors.InvalidIndexError: (slice(None, None, None), None)
```

Here is the code that works:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.pyplot import cm
import numpy as np

df=pd.read_excel('F:\\test\\test.xlsm', sheet_name='sheet1')

df.plot(x='Time',y='CH')
plt.show()
```

input:

[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: At the moment it is difficult to reproduce the error (actually, I can't). Show what's inside `x, y`